# OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit not working as planned, and why are problems with my hierarchy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collision-detection

So, i have this piece of code right here, that should really do the trick. Stick that red cube in this case ( https://prnt.sc/ofsq1j ) on top of the pink one, which is a moving platform.
The problem is that it cannot leave the platform, as you can see in the picture, it should've detected the collision with the black block with the red tile on it, but it doesn't.

This is my hierarchy (https://prnt.sc/ofssmh), and I'm trying to make that BasicCube to be the parent of the Shape.

Those is the BasicCube's properties ( https://prnt.sc/ofsuqk ) and those are the properties for the Shape ( http://prntscr.com/ofsv3s ), and both of them got MeshRenderer's but i don't think those are the problem.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "pShape")
    {
        other.transform.parent = transform;
    }
}

public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "pShape")
    {
        other.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't be about MeshRenderers. According to [Unity's Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)'s second table concerning trigger colliders, make sure your collider setup meets at a 'Y' cell. You have a "Rigidbody Kinematic Collider" and a "Rigidbody Trigger Collider". If you are still having issues, remove the tag condition and check what is colliding with your BasicCube

Comment: the problem still persists after doing this